# How to render component with fetching data changes using await from react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, fetch-api

What i am trying to do is to not fetch all countries data at once, but i want to fetch for the first time 8 countries, and then if show more button clicked I want to fetch once again the next 8 countries. But I want them all to be visible in page, It's sort of infinite scroll but just replacing infinite scroll with clicking show more button. This is the URL of API : "https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all".
This is My code:`

```
import React, { Suspense, useState } from "react";
import { getAllCountries } from "../api/api";
import { defer, useLoaderData, Await } from "react-router-dom";
import CountryCard from "../components/CountryCard";
import Button from "../components/Button";
import ShowMoreIcon from "../components/Icons/ShowMoreIcon";
export const loader = async () => {
  const countries = getAllCountries();
  return defer({ countries });
};

import Loading from "../components/Loading";
const NUM_TO_ADD = 8;
const CountriesPage = () => {
  const { countries } = useLoaderData();
  const [start, setStart] = useState(0);
  const [end, setEnd] = useState(8);

  const showMoreHandler = () => {
    setStart((prev) => prev + NUM_TO_ADD);
    setEnd((prev) => prev + NUM_TO_ADD);
  };

  return (
    <main className="px-16 xl:px-0 xl:mx-auto max-w-7xl">
      <div className="grid grid-cols-[repeat(auto-fit,minmax(250px,1fr))] gap-6 lg:gap-12 mb-12">
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
          <Await resolve={countries}>
            {(data) =>
              data.map((data) => (
                <CountryCard
                  key={data.name.common}
                  countryCapital={data.capital}
                  countryFlag={data.flags.png}
                  countryPopulation={data.population}
                  countryRegion={data.region}
                  countryId={data.cca3}
                  countryName={data.name.common}
                ></CountryCard>
              ))
            }
          </Await>
        </Suspense>
      </div>
      <Button onClick={showMoreHandler} className={"mx-auto flex items-center"}>
        <ShowMoreIcon></ShowMoreIcon>
        Show More
      </Button>
    </main>
  );
};

export default CountriesPage;
```

I tried to useState but that didnt work well. Also I tried to seperate the suspense and await jsx in another file but It didnt work for me.

Comment: What is the specific question, or issue, you have here? What do you need help with? It looks like you have "paginated data" that the "show more" button should "iterate" through. Do you need to request the next "page" of data? Did the app already fetch all the data and the UI just needs to render the next "page"? Something else? Please [edit] to clarify the use case and what any issues/problems are, and include all relevant code in the [mcve].

Comment: The APIs you are hitting don't appear to have an endpoint to request countries by page. See https://gitlab.com/restcountries/restcountries. Seems it's all or nothing.